# For curve =2x^2−5x+2 , if the normal to the curve at point  is parallel to the tangent to the curve when =2 , find the co-ordinates of 

Tags: analysis, derivatives, tangent-line

I'm struggling on the above question.

I have dy/dx as 4x-5
gradientTangent = 3
gradient normal = -1/3

the corresponding y co-ordinate at x=2 is y=0

I have also created the eqn of the tangent and the normal at this point but I don't really understand what the question is asking for or how to find P.

Answer (score 0):

Now for $x_P$ we have $$4x-5=-\frac{1}{3},$$
which gives $$x_P=\frac{7}{6}.$$
Can you end it now?

I got $$P\left(\frac{7}{6},-\frac{10}{9}\right).$$

Comment: thank you, I kept thinking if it is parallel surely the gradient should be 3? thank you

Comment: @Amistry You are welcome!